# Utilse table list for headers in another table in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I want to create two tables in Excel:

**Table 1 -** Contains a list of tasks and a description of the task and possibly some other information on the tasks (eg type, ownership, etc.).

**Table 2** - Contains a list of asset sites, and the columns are the Task 1 list items.  Not all tasks are required at every site, so where a lookup generates a code for accounting purposes.  I then use Powerquery to unpivot the Table 2, to generate a list of task-activity to give to the finance team who create work order numbers is a separate system.

Is there a way to link the Table 1 list to the Table 2 headings, such that when I update/add items to Table 1 it is automatically added to Table 2.

I have been doing it manually at the moment, but think this capability would be useful for a range of follow on, but linked tasks.  I have tried copying the list and pasting as an array but had trouble getting it to work

Comment: You can provide Table 1 and Table 2 samples, it is more helpful.

Comment: Not without VBA. Table headers must be "constants" ie fixed text, not formulas.

Comment: do you have same test case for `Table 2 - Contains a list of asset sites, and the columns are the Task 1 list items.` ? I cannot replicate the flow (and the change to the workflow) u r describing without a sample data... u may use 'table' format (in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/ask)) to format the sample.. ( :